# TestNG Maven - error(red underline) at @Test

Tags: maven, dependencies, testng, pom.xml

```
    error(red underline) at @Test, how to resolve this error.
```

I searched for similar error, there is no similar issue logged before.

```
    code:
    
    package com.testing.Del;

public class NewTest {
    @Test
    public void f() {

        System.out.println("welcome");

    }
}

    
    Details:
    eclipse IDE - Version: Kepler Service Release 2
    
    added testng dependency to the POM file.
    
    Pls help.
```

Is this something I'm missing. I'm new to programming.

Comment: First I strongly recommend to upgrade Eclipse because using old software is usually one problem. (because Kepler is seven years old)... Furthermore your should add your pom file and you should check to run your build on plain command line

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed the latest IDE but the TestNG code looks like this, package com.test.Del;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void f() {
   
   System.out.println("welcome");
  }
} test contains Run All, Run, Debug.

Comment: resolved the issue.